# which firefox version is compatible with selenium 2.52.0? I tried with 44 but it is not opened sometime..Can anyone tell me

Tags: java, selenium

which firefox version is compatible with selenium 2.52.0? I tried with 44 version but it is not get opened sometime..Can anyone tell me which version i can try

Comment: I use Selenium 2.53.0 with firefox 46.0, so you should be able to run any version below 46.0

Answer (score 0):

you can use FF45 version.
It is compatible with selenium 2.52